Confirming negatives in English
I know in English if someone asks:

The picture is not correct, right?

I could answer:

No, it is not correct.


Right, it is not correct.

But what if the negative is in the word itself, such as

The picture is incorrect, right?

Are the above answers still correct?


The picture [is not] correct, right?

As there's negation in the sentence, we say

No, it isn't correct.

Edit
I would probably not say

*Right, it is not correct.

although listeners will likely understand that the message is it is not correct (or it isn't correct).
It would be clearer if it is "You're right; it is not correct."

The picture [is] incorrect, right?

As the negation is in incorrect, we say

Right, it's incorrect.


"Right, it is not correct" is OK, but it would be even clearer if you say "You're right; it is not correct".

Thanks,  @Peter.  I have edited my answer.
